# Facebook API blocks requests from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, aws-lambda

Our app sends a request to Facebook API endpoint.

https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/preview_iframe.php

It works from our team's local machine but when the app gets deployed to lambda, the requests fail. We've tried logging into an EC2 and test it and the requests fail there as well.

Is this something we can rectify on our end?

Comment: Run it only on your home machines?  You link to something that basically 404's.  Meta is blocking it from AWS addresses.

Comment: Is the request going over a private or public network? It will be helpful to see the respond that you are getting.

Comment: @AlbertMarrero it is going through a public network I reckon. Facebook's Graph API is accessible though.

Comment: What is the failure message that you are getting?